# Como fazer arredondamento a cada 5 décimos (0.5)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho um select que retorna a média das colunas. Utilizei o Round para remover algumas casas decimais e arredondar os números.

Os números possíveis dos campos são inteiros de 1 a 5, e ao fazer o select da média aparecem os decimais. Só que a minha necessidade é que esses decimais sejam arredondados para intervalos de 0,5. Exemplo: 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0 etc

Meu select é esse:

```
SELECT 
nomNome,
ROUND(((notaAmbiente + 
notaApresentacaoDasPizzas + 
    notaQualidadeDosProdutos + 
    notaVariedadeDeSabores +
    notaAtendimentoNaLoja +
    notaAtendimentoNoTel +
    notaAgilidadeNaEntrega + 
    notaCustoBeneficio +
    notaPromocoes +
    notaSite +
    notaSatisfacao + notaSatisfacao) / 12), 1) AS notaOpiniao
FROM tbOpiniao
```

Como retorna sem o arredondamento correto: 3,2 (3,199) e 2,3 (2,277)
Como quero que retorne: 3,0 e 2,5

Como fazer isso?

Comment: Dê um exemplo de saída! tipo saiu um valor tem que ficar esse valor ?

Comment: 3,1999 não seria 3,5 ?

Comment: não pois esta abaixo da metade do meio 0,1999 < 0.25.  De 0.25 ate 0.49 arredondaria pra 0.5

Comment: Então não é de 0,5 a 0,5? olha sua questão?

Comment: Eu fiz uma SQL, que no meu entender é a realidade sua, inclusive testado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui com uma conta simples de matemática o que eu queria:

```
SELECT 
nomNome,
ROUND(((notaAmbiente + 
 notaApresentacaoDasPizzas + 
    notaQualidadeDosProdutos + 
    notaVariedadeDeSabores +
    notaAtendimentoNaLoja +
    notaAtendimentoNoTel +
    notaAgilidadeNaEntrega + 
    notaCustoBeneficio +
    notaPromocoes +
    notaSite +
    notaSatisfacao + notaSatisfacao) / 12) / 0.5, 0) * 0.5 AS notaOpiniao
FROM tbOpiniao
```

Agora só estou retornando os valores {1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5} como o desejado.

Comment: ta certo mesmo ?

Comment: Sim, testado e funcionando!!

Comment: Eu prefiro a expressão `) * 2, 0) / 2`, mas dá na mesma.

Answer (score 1):

Assim:

```
SELECT id, valor, decimalvalue,
       (CASE WHEN ((decimalvalue) < .25)
                  THEN TRUNCATE(valor,0)
             WHEN ((decimalvalue) > .25 AND (decimalvalue) < .49)
                  THEN TRUNCATE(valor,0) + .5
             WHEN ((decimalvalue) > .5 AND (decimalvalue) < .75)
                  THEN ((valor - decimalvalue) + .5)
             WHEN (decimalvalue > .75) 
                  THEN (1 - decimalvalue + valor)
             ELSE (valor)
       END) as newvalor
FROM (
SELECT id, 
       valor, 
       valor - TRUNCATE(valor,0) as decimalvalue        
FROM new_table) AS NEWTABLE
```

Exemplo: [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e285/1)